# C# random file in use by other process errors

Tags: c#, process, aac

I have written an app that takes an uncompressed .wav file and encodes into a flac file, mp3 file, and aac file. The flac and mp3 work fine, but when doing the aac encoding (using the [Nero AAC encoder](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nerodigital-nero-aac-codec.php)) I **randomly** get IOExceptions about the file being in use. Sometimes - but not as often - it happens while the file is generated - How can the file that my process created be in use by another? But more often it is when I write the meta tags using TagLib that I get the errors. So I rigged up the code to run [sysinternal's handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) on the file in question upon an IO error, but it returns the fact that there are no handles on the file. Is this just an inherent problem with the Nero aac encoder?

```
try
{
if ( ! Directory.Exists( es.dest ) )
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory( Path.GetDirectoryName( es.dest ) );
    }
    if ( File.Exists( es.dest ) ) { File.Delete( es.dest ); }
    bool CommandGenerated = enc.GenerateCommandLine();

    string procOutput = String.Empty;
    if ( CommandGenerated )
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine( "Starting:" );
        p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( current_config_exe );
        p.StartInfo.FileName = current_config_exe;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = enc.ToString();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();

        procOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        int exit_code = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();
        p.Dispose();
        string exit_msg = "Encoder exitcode: " + exit_code + "\n";
        if ( exit_code != 0 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "There was a problem. Do you want to continue? (y/n) (Default = y)" );
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            if ( response.ToLower() == "n" )
            {
                throw new Exception( "Note: " + exit_msg );
            }
        }
        else if ( es.use_taglib_for_meta && enc.metaswitches != null )
        {
            Meta meta = new Meta( es.dest );
            if ( meta.SetMetaTags( enc.metaswitches, true ) )
            {
                WriteLog( "Meta tags successfully wriiten to: \n" + es.dest, true, false );
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLog( "Meta tags NOT wriiten to: " + es.dest, true );
            }
        }
    }
}
catch ( IOException ex )
    {
        Handler.GetHoldingProcess( es.dest );
        Program.WriteLog( "(writing track to file) Error saving file " + es.dest + ":\n" + ex, true );
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You should use a tool like `FileMon` or `ProcMon` to see what's opening the file. Odds are it's being indexed or virus scanned very briefly, so you won't be able to see it without capturing a log while it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you an other SysInternals tool - [filemon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642)

1. Put breakpoint on method which complaining IOException
2. Run the application in debug mode from VS
3. When VS stop on breakpoint - launch filemon.exe
4. Press F5 in VS (continue execution)
5. When exception raised - pause filemon.exe and start analysing what is going on with file

To simplify investigation you can setup a filter in filemon by file or process name
Good luck!

Comment: I used procmon.exe since filemon is no longer available. While it didn't show me the exact lock, what it did show me was the Windows Media Player (wmplayer.exe - which I don't even use) was trying to catalog these files as they were were written. [this link](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/620757-wmplayerexe-running-in-background/page__st__15) led me to disable the Windows Media plugin in Windows Sideshow and the problem appears to be solved.